# Is there a shorthand for Boolean `match` expressions?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Is there a shorthand for the `match` expression with `isVertical` here?

```ml
let bulmaContentParentTile isVertical nodes =
    let cssClasses =
        let cssDefault = [ "tile"; "is-parent" ]
        match isVertical with
        | true -> cssDefault @ [ "is-vertical" ]
        | _ -> cssDefault

    div [ attr.classes cssClasses ] nodes
```

I assume that an expression like `match isVertical with` is so common that there is a shorthand like the one we have for `function`, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's just an `if`-expression:

```ml
    let cssClasses =
        let cssDefault = [ "tile"; "is-parent" ]
        if isVertical then
            cssDefault @ [ "is-vertical" ]
        else cssDefault
```

Quoting from the F# [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/conditional-expressions-if-then-else):

> Unlike in other languages, the `if...then...else` construct is an expression, not a statement. That means that it produces a value, which is the value of the last expression in the branch that executes.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit off-topic but you can build your list by using [Sequence Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences#sequence-expressions) which is IMHO more readable for this use case.

```
let cssClasses = [
    "tile"
    "is-parent"
    if isVertical then
        "is-vertical"
]
```